# Add custom entity search to Drupal core search

Tags: entities, panels, search, database

Is it possible to add results for a custom entity search to the results returned by Drupal core node search? At what point in the process would it be possible to add to the core search results?

I've been looking into `hook_query_alter`, but I'm not sure where you'd add in the adjusted query parameters for a custom entity. The options mainly seem to be related to adjusting the typical node search.

The end goal is to add the results for [Page Manager Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager_search) to a standard search, but I keep hitting a wall every way I try to go about it.